# WPF ComboBox EditTemplate - TextBox border is not going away

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, devexpress

I am using a DEVExpress combobox and have enabled type ahead (Auto search functioanlity). In combo box I am showing two things. First item is an image and second item is a value(id).

Mine problem is that the value border is getting outside to combo box while showing at UI at run time. I tried setting margin but its of no use. My application is having option to select theme and for some of the theme its getting hazy.

Any idea how to get rid of this ?

see the first one is looking fine however the below one is bit hazy if i change the theme.

[image]

I am using below code for the same.

```
<dvEx:ComboBoxEdit.EditTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=(dxe:BaseEdit.OwnerEdit).SelectedItem.Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Margin="8, 0, 4, 0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_Editor" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</dvEx:ComboBoxEdit.EditTemplate>

<dvEx:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DesignSelectViewModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="8, 0, 4, 0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</dvEx:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish your task I suggest you to override the `TextBox.Template` as follows to make it theme-independent and remove it's focused state (border and background):

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_Editor">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="Root" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Value="0.75"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Root" Value="0.5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

Related MSDN article: [TextBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)